# Force to upload 1 image with the same name in Codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload, multiplication

I have made an image upload page. this all works smooth.

My problem is when i upload an image called filename.jpg and i upload it again the same image uploads but changes the name to filename1.jpg

how can i force this and make a message with something like 'the image you upload was allready uploaded'

thanks

Comment: How could your code knows both images are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the change in filename was initiated by the os of server computer
to produce the promt you have to check the file name for duplicates while you are uploading
using the php script
if you have a database which stores the filenames then it is very easy

Comment: i don't have a database. it just uploads and stores the image in an directory of my approot

Comment: then you have to use file_exists() of php

Comment: $FILE['filename'] is to be passed as argument if you dont know the name

Comment: maybe there's an option the upload library? i read a lot of things like file_overrides but i don't know which one it is.

Comment: i dont know more about upload library

Comment: but i have a suggestion that you must include flag php in your question it will bring attention of much more audience

Comment: what do you mean? i don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: or add flag php to ur question by yoursself